# AppBarButton isEnabled=false but display button enabled

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a command bar with two buttons, the first is enabled and visible, the second is disabled and not visible, at the click of the first, I view the second one.
When the second back is visible it is not possible to click, but it is visually enabled.

code:

```
      <CommandBar Background="Transparent" DefaultLabelPosition="Right" IsDynamicOverflowEnabled="True">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
                    FontSize="40"
                    Text="Command Bar"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Layout" Click="AppBarButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" Label="Layout">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE81E;" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="la1" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Collapsed"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Layout" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" Label="Layout">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE81E;" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
```

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        la1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

this is a screenshot, both are visible, the first enabled and the second disabled, but the button display is both enabled.

[image]

I dont want enable it. The problem is the graphic of button, the button isn't enabled but the UI of button indicate the button enabled

Comment: What does your style "AppBarButtonRevealStyle" look like?

Comment: it's default AppBarButtonRevealStyle style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay as i understand you want this

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    la1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    if(la1.IsEnabled == false)
    {
        la1.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled"];
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Alternately you can create your own style using Blend.

Comment: Ok but why is not it automatic? If the button is visible it changes the foreground directly.

Comment: @Andrea485 as i suggested you have to check it in appbarbutton default style using blend or also check default style given in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299105.aspx in disabled state you have to set the brush i used in my above answer.